Logic ambiguity of proving irrationality of root 2
I'm a first-year math student and we recently learnt the method of proving $\sqrt2$ is irrational, which involves using $\frac{p}{q}$ to show that both $p$ and $q$ are even which in turn are divisible by 2.
I have no problem with the development of steps, but I don't fully comprehend, or at least not certain about $\frac{p}{q}$ have a common divisor is the core reason of $\sqrt2$ not being rational. As $2r^2=q$ only shows that  $\frac{p}{q}$  is not the most simplified form of a potential rational number representing $\sqrt2$. If I use $2p^,=p$ and $2q^,=q$ to reconstruct the process it would be an endless loop. Is the fact that there is a never-ending loop of trying to make it as a simplist form indicate the failure of consturting $\sqrt2$ in fractional form which leads to irrationality or just simply due to $p$ and $q$ can not have a common divisor when we write it as $\frac{p}{q}$?

It can't be a never-ending loop because $p' <p$ and $q'<q$. There can't be a strictly decreasing sequence of positive integers.

Thats a good point! Thanks for that. So when it reaches the point of being 1, it shows a strong contradiction.

Yes. Those are two variants of that proof: One assumes from the beginning that the fraction is reduced and then we find they are both even, the other begin with the fraction and iterate the process to get an infinite strictly decreasing sequence of positive integers. In both variants one gets a contradiction.

In the proof, you may use the fact that we can assume $\frac{p}{q}$ as the simplest form of a rational number where $p,q$ are integers and $q$ is not equal to $0$ where $\gcd(p,q)=1$.
So basically we reach a contradiction according to our assumption that $p/q$ is not the simplest form.
Hence we can say that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

You are welcome! Please use $\frac{p}{q}$ instead of \frac{p}{q}. You can see more here
